# Android Card View Activity is laggy

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have this fragment with 8 card views and 8 images  but when I use the app on my phone it lags when i'm on this fragment and this fragment alone, anyone know why that is?
Each card directs to a different activity on click so maybe that is what is causing the lag?

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

\<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundBlack"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"\>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:text="Inventario"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
        <GridLayout
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardMaquinas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/receiptImage"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/maquina"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Maquinas"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardTintas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ink"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:text="Tintas"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardVasos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/inkcup"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Vasos de tinta"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardAgujas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/agujas"/>
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Agujas y cartuchos"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardFuentes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/fuentes"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Fuentes"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPiel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/piel" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Piel sintetica"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPuntas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/cartuchos" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Tubos y puntas"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardGuantes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/guantes" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Guantes"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
        </GridLayout>
    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:visibility="invisible">
    
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
package com.example.tattostudio.ui.home;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.tattostudio.R;
import com.example.tattostudio.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.AgujasInventario;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.FuentesInventario;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.GuantesInventario;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.MaquinasInventario;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.PielInventario;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.PuntasInventario;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.TintasActivity;
import com.example.tattostudio.inventariostuff.VasosInventario;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        HomeViewModel homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        return root;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        androidx.cardview.widget.CardView card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8;
    
        card1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardMaquinas);
        card2 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardTintas);
        card3 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardVasos);
        card4 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardAgujas);
        card5 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardFuentes);
        card6 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardPiel);
        card7 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardPuntas);
        card8 = getView().findViewById(R.id.cardGuantes);
    
        card1.setOnClickListener(this);
        card2.setOnClickListener(this);
        card3.setOnClickListener(this);
        card4.setOnClickListener(this);
        card5.setOnClickListener(this);
        card6.setOnClickListener(this);
        card7.setOnClickListener(this);
        card8.setOnClickListener(this);
    
    }
    
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i;
    
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.cardMaquinas:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), MaquinasInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardTintas:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), TintasActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardVasos:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), VasosInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardAgujas:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), AgujasInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardFuentes:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), FuentesInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardPiel:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), PielInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardPuntas:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), PuntasInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.cardGuantes:
                i = new Intent(getActivity(), GuantesInventario.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

I tried using smaller images but I suspect the lag comes from the code being unoptimized, i'm a begginer developer on android so i'm not really sure what can I do to optimize it and make it run smooth on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your ScrollView becasuse you closed Scrollview at top without including other UI into it.It should close at the end of XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundBlack"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:text="Inventario"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
        <GridLayout
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardMaquinas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/receiptImage"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/maquina"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Maquinas"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardTintas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ink"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:text="Tintas"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardVasos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/inkcup"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Vasos de tinta"
                        android:textSize="13dp"/>
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardAgujas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:elevation="60dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/agujas"/>
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Agujas y cartuchos"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardFuentes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/fuentes"
                        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Fuentes"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPiel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/piel" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Piel sintetica"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardPuntas"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/cartuchos" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Tubos y puntas"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardGuantes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:elevation="60dp">
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">
    
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="120dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/guantes" />
    
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="Guantes"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
        </GridLayout>
    
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:visibility="invisible">
    
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Fixed that but the fragment still lags a lot :(